# Indexing and subscripts for R arrays with variable dimensions

Tags: arrays, r

Suppose you have an n-dimensional, homogeneous data structure (array) in R with a variable but fixed number of dimensions:

```
n_dim <- 3
n_row <- 3
a <- array(seq(n_row ^ n_dim), dim = rep(n_row, n_dim))

a
>, , 1
>
>     [,1] [,2] [,3]
>[1,]    1    4    7
>[2,]    2    5    8
>[3,]    3    6    9
>[..]
```

Is there a simple syntax to access a subscript of a given dimension, instead of counting the commas from `n_dim` or counting the position with 1-dim positions `a[c(1,...)]`? Is there any `a[get row in dim]` method that provides this already?

```
# Give me the 1st row of the "last" dimension
expr <- paste0("a[",
                paste0(rep(", ", n_dim - 1), collapse = ""),
                x,
                "]")
expr
> [1] "a[, , 1]"

eval(parse(text = expr))
>     [,1] [,2] [,3]
>[1,]    1    4    7
>[2,]    2    5    8
>[3,]    3    6    9
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be `abind`

```
library(abind)
asub(a, 1, n_dim)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    7
#[2,]    2    5    8
#[3,]    3    6    9
```